# How to add JavaScript response to more than one forearch result

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

I currently have a PHP script that works well, but when it comes to adding JavaScript I'm having a small issue.

What I'm trying to achieve is display the results in a php foreach loop which works well, but I have a onclick JavaScript function that is suppose to display results in the same row as the results of the foreach loop, but instead it changes the current value of only one results.

So I currently have four car types with a price. When one is selected I would like the name and price to display on top of the [echo "Select:" . $name] line.

My current code is this:

```
<?php
   $cars = array(
   array("Volvo",40.000),
   array("BMW",45.000),
   array("Saab",50.000),
   array("Land Rover",60.000)
   );

foreach($cars as $key){
    $name = $key[0];
    $price = $key[1];

    echo "<span id='$name'></span> <span id='$price'></span><br />";
    echo "Select: " . $name;
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function grabData(d){
         document.getElementById("<?php echo $price; ?>").innerHTML = d.getAttribute("data-price");
         document.getElementById("<?php echo $name; ?>").innerHTML = d.getAttribute("data-title");
     }
 </script>
 <input onclick="grabData(this);" type="radio" name="rate" data-price="<?php echo $key[1]; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $key[0]; ?>"><br />
<?php
}
?>
```

So if all options are selected the end results should look like this:

```
Volvo 40
Volvo: 
BMW 45
BMW:
Saab 50
Saab: 
Land Rover 60
Land Rover:
```

Any help or direction is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really using the price as the ID of the span that displays the price? What if you have two cars with the same price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is simply defining the same function over and over. When it gets called, it will call the last definition, not the one for that element in the loop.

You should just define the function once, and add additional parameters. Then you can call it with different parameters for each element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function grabData(d, priceid, nameid){
    document.getElementById(priceid).innerHTML = d.getAttribute("data-price");
    document.getElementById(nameid).innerHTML = d.getAttribute("data-title");
}
</script>

<?php
$cars = array(
              array("Volvo",40.000),
              array("BMW",45.000),
              array("Saab",50.000),
              array("Land Rover",60.000)
              );

foreach($cars as $key){
    $name = $key[0];
    $price = $key[1];

    echo "<span id='$name'></span> <span id='$price'></span><br />";
    echo "Select: " . $name;
    ?>
    <input onclick="grabData(this, '<?php echo $price; ?>', '<?php echo $name; ?>');" type="radio" name="rate" data-price="<?php echo $key[1]; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $key[0]; ?>"><br />
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the script part as a string in a variable and echo it using php, php sees every `<?php  ?>` as a different coding block.